# Having Issue with store non property object

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, xcode

I am trying to save store a custom file using `UserDefaults`, but my app crashesh due to :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my code , in my custom class I declare an empty array

```
class AppDefualts: NSObject {

    var downloadedURLArray = [DownloadFile]() //Declare an empty array


    override init() {
        super.init()


        downloadedURLArray = loadStoredURL()
     }


//Store data
func addStored(file:DownloadFile) {

    //Add URL to array and save it
    downloadedURLArray.append(file)

    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: downloadedURLArray)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "storedURL")
}

 //Load:
    func loadStoredURL() -> Array<DownloadFile> {

        let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "storedURL")
        downloadedURLArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data!) as? [DownloadFile] ?? [DownloadFile]()
        return downloadedURLArray

    }
```

Any help would be great

EDIT 1 :
I added `NSCoding` protocols :

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(downloadedURLArray, forKey: "storedURL")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    downloadedURLArray = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "storedURL") as! [DownloadFile]
}
```

now app crashes due to this :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -encodeObject:forKey:
>   cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a
>   concrete instance!'

Comment: Read data storage guidelines. What you are trying to do is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the custom object in `UserDefault` then you have to do Encoding/Decoding. Your custom object suppose to confirm to the `NSCoding` Protocol.

**Store into UserDefault :** You have to convert you object in to `NSData` and store them into `UserDefault` by using `NSKeyedArchiver`

**Get from UserDefault :** Get the NSData from `USerDefault` and convert into Custom object by using `NSKeyedUnArchiver`

Refer the link to [convert custom object into NSData and vice versa](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/)

**Example: custom object which confirms NSCoding protocol**

```
class Book: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var title: String
    var author: String
    var pageCount: Int
    var categories: [String]
    var available: Bool

    // Memberwise initializer
    init(title: String, author: String, pageCount: Int, categories: [String], available: Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.pageCount = pageCount
        self.categories = categories
        self.available = available
    }

    // MARK: NSCoding

    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let title = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as? String,
            let author = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("author") as? String,
            let categories = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("categories") as? [String]
            else { return nil }

        self.init(
            title: title,
            author: author,
            pageCount: decoder.decodeIntegerForKey("pageCount"),
            categories: categories,
            available: decoder.decodeBoolForKey("available")
        )
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(self.title, forKey: "title")
        coder.encodeObject(self.author, forKey: "author")
        coder.encodeInt(Int32(self.pageCount), forKey: "pageCount")
        coder.encodeObject(self.categories, forKey: "categories")
        coder.encodeBool(self.available, forKey: "available")
    }
}
```

Comment: I did same things , store data using  `NSKeyedArchiver` and load it with `NSKeyedUnarchiver ` did you read my codes?

Comment: @Mc.Lover But your custom object not confirming to the NSCoding protocol

Comment: @Mc.Lover I have updated my answer with example class which is confirming to NSCoding protocol

Comment: I think I need to create a custom class which is separate from this class , I will try it

Comment: @Mc.Lover AppDefualts  class encoding/decoding is correct. can you add the DownloadFile class code?. you have to confirm NSCoding protocol in the DownloadFile class also

Comment: AppDefualts class sis using array of DownloadFile class. If you are encoding AppDefaults class then DownloadFile class should also confirm the NSCoding protocol

Comment: DownloadFile is a download manager project from GitHub I have a table view and I have to store Download files so when user leave the download view controller and come back to it I like to store display all files :
https://github.com/MaxOstPM/iosDownloadManager-Swift-

Comment: Then you can't archive this class because AppDefualts using another class which is not confirming to the NSCoding protocol. if downloadedURLArray property only storing the file paths then make that property as array of string then you are able to archive the class

Comment: What is the solution ?

Comment: Solution will be based on what kind of data downloadedURLArray property is holding ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146755/discussion-between-subramanian-and-mc-lover).